# SAS Erase all lines that have a particular condition

Tags: sas

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
Name Option
---- ------
A    X
A    
B
C    X
B
E    X
C
```

I want to delete all lines in which in column "Name" there is a letter that in column Option as an X

In the previous example for instance I would like to delete all lines in which in Name there is A, C and E.
How could I do?

I am a beginner in Sas

Comment: Your request is not clear. Do you want to filter based on the values of the variable NAME (such as `indexc(upcase(name),'ABC')`) or the variable OPTION (such as `option='X'`)?  Or perhaps some logic that requires testing the values of both of those variables?

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    if(option = 'X') then delete;
run;
```

An important note about `delete`: no other code will run after this statement. If you have code after this conditional then it will not execute. This is a unique feature of `delete`.

You can optionally use `remove` instead, in which case additional code will run after the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL solution if you want to delete **ALL** rows corresponding to a name that has **any** row with `OPTION='X'`

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input name $ option $;
datalines;
A    X
A    
B
C    X
B
E    X
C
;
proc sql;
  create table remove as
  select distinct(name) from have
  where option = 'X'
  ;

  create table want as
  select * from have
  where name not in (select name from remove)
  ;
quit;
```

The following code is an old-school SAS technique of SORT and MERGE and produces the same result.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by name;
data filter;
  set have;
  by name;
  where option='X';
  if first.name;
data want;
  merge have filter(in=residue);
  by name;
  if not residue;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginning let's explain some basic terminology.  A DATESET consists of OBSERVATIONS (what you might call a row or a line) and VARIABLES (what you might call a column).

If you want to select observations that contain particular values then you probably want to use the IN operator.

```
data want;
   set have;
   where name not in ('A','B','C');
run;
```

If you want to select observations where the value of the variable NAME contains a particular letter then you probably want to use INDEXC() function.

```
data want;
   set have;
   where not indexc(name,'ABC');
run;
```

If you do not care about the case of the letters then you could convert the values to uppercase and test.  Or switch to the FINDC() function instead, which has more options, including one to ignore the case when checking for letter matches.

```
data want;
   set have;
   where not findc(name,'ABC','i');
run;
```